# Is there anyway to break through Windows 7 IO limitations in Python?

Tags: python, windows-7

I've written a Python program that will automatically walk through a file system and check if some directories and files are not removed and their fingerprints- like file lengths, checksums, md5 hash values, etc- not changed. If a file is removed or its content changed, the program will try to recover it from a backup package.

This program runs perfectly under Linux/OS X system, but doesn't work in Windows 7. I know that Windows 7 has its UAC system that will prevent program from changing files under directories like "C:\", "C:\Boot", "C:\Program Files", etc. But even when I disabled UAC and ran that program with Administrator privilege, it still didn't work.

Is there any way to programmatically invoke a privilege elevation request so that I can afterward read or write under those directories?